# Role 'permissions' stay when changing role

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authorization

I have an ASP.NET core MVC site with a SQLite data connection using ASP.NET core authorization like this:

```
// Startup.ConfigureServices
services.AddAuthorization(e =>
{
    e.AddPolicy(Policies.UserRead, b => b.RequireRole("Editor", "Root"));
}
```

This is one of the policies which restricts access to site with user information. (`Policies.UserRead` is a constant `string`). This policy is then applied to the view like this:

```
[Authorize(Policies.UserRead)]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
}
```

This works great and only users with the role `Editor` or `Root` can access the view. But problems arises when the role of a user is changed while logged in. e.g.

- User A (role `Editor`) logs in and uses `Index()` - *success*
- User B (role `Root`) logs in and removes the role `Editor` from user A
- User A  uses `Index()` - *still success*

You would expect that user A can not access `Index()` anymore because he no longer as the role `Editor`. Buuuut he still can - as long as he does not log out and log back in again, because relogging fixes this issue. It seems like somebody (I think `ClaimsPrincipal` is the culprit here) cached the role - which would be `OK` if I knew how to invalidate the cache...

---

Role changing code:

```
// get the user whos role is changed
var targetUser = await _context.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == model.Id);
if (targetUser == null) return NotFound();

// get the user who changes the role
var sourceUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
if (sourceUser == null) return RedirectToAction("Index");

// remove the current role
await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(targetUser, targetUser.Role.ToString());

// add to the new role
await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(targetUser, model.Role.ToString());

// update & save the changes
_context.Update(targetUser);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This is basically the code I use to change the role of a user (I cut out the view/model parts because they are irrelevant). Notes:

- `targetUser` and `sourceUser` are both `ApplicationUser` (which implements `IdentityUser`).
- `_userManger` is - who would have thought - of the type `UserManager<ApplicationManger>`

---

I tried to relog the user using `SignInManger<>` but it seems like you can only log out the current user - which would be the user changing the role and not the user whose role would be changed.

---

What am I missing? It would be nice if the user would not have to do anything (e.g. sign back in) in order to *"refresh"* the user role.

Comment: Are you using cookie authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the user's role claims are stored in the cookie(default implementation of aspnet identity) so unless the user sign out even if the user's roles change,  authorization result does not change. The solution is to use `ValidateAsync` event. [Example](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/cookie.html#reacting-to-back-end-changes) exists in the official docs.

Another possible solution is to exclude role claims from cookie and use claims transformation.

For this you need to override the `CreateAsync` method of `UserClaimsPrincipalFactory` see this [article](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) how to change claims. Then you can use [claims transformation](http://benfoster.io/blog/customising-claims-transformation-in-aspnet-core-identity) to add role claims.